# python multipart post not working only with pyinstaller. It's perfectly working with vscode run python file

Tags: python, tkinter, http-post, multipartform-data

```
from tkinter import filedialog

self.file = filedialog.askopenfile(
            mode="r", filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")]
        )
```

when I pass above file into POST like below.

It's working with vscode "Run Python File"

but after compile with pyinstaller into exe.

POST worked and return status 200, but It's not uploading.

I'm not sure It's kind of absoulute path problems.

```
    field_data = {
        "data": (None, json.dumps(data), "application/json"),
        "file": (
            os.path.basename(file.name),
            open(os.path.abspath(file.name), "rb"),
            "multipart/form-data",
        ),
    }
    m = MultipartEncoder(fields=field_data)
    headers = {"Content-Type": m.content_type}

    API_ENDPOINT = (
        "https://uploadfile"
    )

    session = requests.Session()
    session.trust_env = False
    r = session.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, data=m, headers=headers)
```

Comment: *"It's not working at all"* means nothing to us.  Is there any error? If yes, post the full error traceback.

Comment: I'm sorry It's not in detail. POST worked perfectly and return 200
but file was not uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
r = session.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, data=json.dumps(data), files={'file': open(os.path.abspath(file.name), "rb")}, headers=headers)
```